# Jenkins java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when parsing POM

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

When running maven jobs on Linux, Jenkins encounters the following error:

```
FATAL: org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/plexus/ContainerConfiguration;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.<init>(Lorg/codehaus/plexus/ContainerConfiguration;)V
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:166)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderUtils.buildPlexusContainer(MavenEmbedderUtils.java:159)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:109)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.MavenUtil.createEmbedder(MavenUtil.java:212)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1295)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$PomParser.invoke(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1098)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:991)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:969)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.parsePoms(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:960)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:679)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:537)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILUREs
```

This failure occurs regardless of project, on any pom(both made in Windows, and made in Linux).

Jenkins processes without any issues on Windows.

Logs are pretty weird, too:

```
02-Nov-2015 11:51:35.963 INFO [pool-6-thread-2] null.null Started initialization
```

Comment: The Tomcat startup logs are weird, too: